# Прокрутка в слайдере

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Как убрать в стандартном слайдере Bootstrap цикличную прокрутку, и сделать так, чтобы на первый слайд перекидывало только при достижении конца.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000,
    })
});
```

Comment: А чем циклическая прокрутка отличается от перекидывания на первый слайд при достижении конца?

Comment: там однотипна инфа поэтому нужно чтоб было видно, что слайдер закончился и просмотр начинается снова

Comment: Какой-то очень скудный набор параметров у этой карусели. Можно сделать так: выставить `interval` в 0 (или `false`, как предлагает документация) и использовать `.carousel('next')` и `.carousel(0)` в функции, которая будет периодически вызываться.